# Hadoop accessing 3rd party libraries from local file system of a Hadoop node

Tags: java, hadoop, filenotfoundexception

I have a jar file on all my Hadoop nodes at `/home/ubuntu/libs/javacv-0.9.jar` , with some other jar files.

When my *MapReduce* application is executing on *Hadoop* nodes, I am getting this exception

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist hdfs://192.168.0.18:50000/home/ubuntu/libs/javacv-0.9.jar
```

How can I resolve this exception? How can my jar running in Hadoop access 3rd party libraries from the local file system of the Hadoop node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to copy your file to HDFS and not to the local filesystem.

To copy files to HDFS you need to use:

```
hadoop fs -put localfile hdfsPath
```

Other option is to change the file path to:

```
file:///home/ubuntu/libs/javacv-0.9.jar
```

To add jar files to the classpath, take a look at [DistributedCache](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/filecache/DistributedCache.html):

```
DistributedCache.addFileToClassPath(new Path("file:///home/ubuntu/libs/javacv-0.9.jar"), job);
```

You may need to iterate over all jar files in that directory.

Comment: Thanks Paulo, I have 50 jar files in the lib folder. Do I need to specify all the entries one by one or Is there any better way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to use [distributed cache](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/filecache/DistributedCache.html)'s `addFileToClassPath(new Path("/myapp/mylib.jar"), job);` to submit the Jar files that should be added to the classpath of your mapper and reducer tasks.

> Note: Make sure you copy the jar file to HDFS first.

You could even add jar files to class path by using hadoop command line argument `-libjars <jar_file>`.

> Note: Make sure your MapReduce application implements [ToolRunner](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/util/ToolRunner.html) to allow `-libjars` option from command line.