# Hadoop java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist:

Tags: java, hadoop, filenotfoundexception

`/home/ubuntu/libs/javacv-0.9.jar`

javacv-0.9-jar files exists on the local file system of all the hadoop nodes in my cluster.

I am still getting the exception:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: 
hdfs://192.168.0.18:50000/home/ubuntu/libs/javacv-0.9.jar


at   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$17.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1072)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$17.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1064)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1064)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.getFileStatus(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:288)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.getFileStatus(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:224)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.determineTimestamps(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:99)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.determineTimestampsAndCacheVisibilities(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:57)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.copyAndConfigureFiles(JobSubmitter.java:265)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.copyAndConfigureFiles(JobSubmitter.java:301)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:389)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1285)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1282)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1614)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1282)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1303)
at com.emadbarsoum.map.FindFaces.run(FindFaces.java:155)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
at com.emadbarsoum.map.FindFaces.main(FindFaces.java:171)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver$ProgramDescription.invoke(ProgramDriver.java:72)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.run(ProgramDriver.java:145)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.driver(ProgramDriver.java:153)
at com.emadbarsoum.driver.HVisionDriver.main(HVisionDriver.java:89)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
```

I do not know why is this coming. I do not want to put my jars and libs in HDFS. How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Can you show your command / call?

Comment: Are you using the 'hadoop jar' command?

Comment: Go through this link:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28213244/hadoop-accessing-3rd-party-libraries-from-local-file-system-of-a-hadoop-node

Hope this helps you.