# Hadoop Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.6.0.jar even though that file exists

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase, hdfs

I am working with hadoop-2.6.0 and hbase-0.98.9. While running the hadoop job, it is throwing  java.io.FileNotFoundException even though that file exists and also exists in the classpath, but still it is looking for in hdfs:// path. What could be the problem? I did check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28213244/hadoop-accessing-3rd-party-libraries-from-local-file-system-of-a-hadoop-node), but that question is for third party jars. Here it is in the classpath.  Here is the error.

```html
15/05/23 02:08:39 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection, connectString=localhost:2181 sessionTimeout=90000 watcher=hconnection-0x6737ca, quorum=localhost:2181, baseZNode=/hbase
15/05/23 02:08:39 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
15/05/23 02:08:39 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Socket connection established to localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, initiating session
15/05/23 02:08:39 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, sessionid = 0x14d7fd352eb000c, negotiated timeout = 40000
15/05/23 02:08:40 INFO mapreduce.TableOutputFormat: Created table instance for Energy
15/05/23 02:08:40 WARN mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Hadoop command-line option parsing not performed. Implement the Tool interface and execute your application with ToolRunner to remedy this.
15/05/23 02:08:40 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Cleaning up the staging area file:/home/vijaykumar/hadoop/hadoop_tmpdir/mapred/staging/vijaykumar1706101359/.staging/job_local1706101359_0001
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://localhost:54310/home/vijaykumar/hadoop/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.6.0.jar
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$18.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1122)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$18.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1114)
 at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1114)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.getFileStatus(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:288)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.getFileStatus(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:224)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.determineTimestamps(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:93)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.determineTimestampsAndCacheVisibilities(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:57)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.copyAndConfigureFiles(JobSubmitter.java:269)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.copyAndConfigureFiles(JobSubmitter.java:390)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:483)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1296)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1293)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
 at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1293)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1314)
 at habseWrite.run(habseWrite.java:142)
 at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
 at habseWrite.main(habseWrite.java:107)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
 at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
 at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
```

Mapper class

```html
public static class WriteMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, IntWritable, Text>  {

   IntWritable k = new IntWritable();
   Text res = new Text();
   public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    
    String val = value.toString();
    int row = val.hashCode();
    k.set(row);
    res.set(val);
    context.write(k, res);
      }

 }
```

Reducer code

```html
public static class WriteReducer extends TableReducer<IntWritable, Text, Text>  {
    public static final byte[] area = "Area".getBytes();
    public static final byte[] prop = "Property".getBytes();
    private Text rowkey = new Text();
    private int rowCount = 0;
    public void reduce(IntWritable key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
   String X1 = "",X2="",X3="",X4="",X5="",
     X6="",X7="",X8="",Y1="",Y2="";
      for (Text val : values) {
        String[] v = val.toString().split("\t");
        X1 = v[0];
        X2 = v[1];
        X3 = v[2];
        X4 = v[3];
        X5 = v[4];
        X6 = v[5];
        X7 = v[6];
        X8 = v[7];
        Y1 = v[8];
        Y2 = v[9];
      }
      String k = "row"+rowCount;
      Put put = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(k.toString()));
      put.add(area, "X1".getBytes(), Bytes.toBytes(X1));
      put.add(area, "X5".getBytes(), Bytes.toBytes(X5));
      put.add(area, "X6".getBytes(), Bytes.toBytes(X6));
      put.add(area, "Y1".getBytes(), Bytes.toBytes(Y1));
      put.add(area, "Y2".getBytes(), Bytes.toBytes(Y2));
      put.add(prop, "X2".getBytes(), Bytes.toBytes(X2));
      put.add(prop, "X3".getBytes(), Bytes.toBytes(X3));
      put.add(prop, "X4".getBytes(), Bytes.toBytes(X4));
      put.add(prop, "X7".getBytes(), Bytes.toBytes(X7));
      put.add(prop, "X8".getBytes(), Bytes.toBytes(X8));
      rowCount++;
      rowkey.set(k); 
      context.write(rowkey, put);
    }
 }
```

And main

```html
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
         int res = ToolRunner.run(new Configuration(), new habseWrite(), args);
         System.exit(res);
   }
 
 public int run(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, InterruptedException {
  Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create(); 
        String inputPath = args[0];  
        Job job = new Job(conf,"HBase_write");        
        job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);  
        job.setJarByClass(habseWrite.class);  
        job.setMapperClass(habseWrite.WriteMapper.class);
        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
        
        
        TableMapReduceUtil.initTableReducerJob(
            "Energy",        // output table
            WriteReducer.class,    // reducer class
            job);
        job.setNumReduceTasks(1);        
        
        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, inputPath);  
        return(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1 );
        
 }
```

Comment: The error is not a CLASSPATH issue, but an HDFS distributed cache issue. The job submitter fails to cleanup the cache because the file is not present. This occurs *after* your job attempt. I think the more relevant error is the previous one.

Comment: Previous you mean, the warning ? I don't see any other error previous to this. Can you please elaborate ?

Comment: Yes, the warning. The exception is INFO only.

Comment: Now the warning is gone, but still there is exception.